# Can I use external css in eBay.co.uk custom description for a listing?

Tags: css

I'm making custom description in one listing on ebay.co.uk with just html/inline css. I tried to use external css link, but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Inline css is working.  External and Internal not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/....../css/style.css">

<p>some paragraph</p>
```

Please note ebay cut head and body tags, so I skipped them in the example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a stylesheet or `<style>` tags, but you can use inline styles on divs.

`<div style=""></div>`